# Capybara is not finding fields when form has file_field input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a very strange problem with my specs. I have form that looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @provider] do |f|
  = f.input :provider_type_id
  = f.input :provider_username
  = f.input :first_name
  = f.input :last_name
  = f.input :athena_health_provider_id
  = f.input :display_name
  = f.input :specialty
  = f.input :entity_type
  = f.input :home_department
  = f.input :billable
  = f.input :npi
  = f.input :ansi_specialty_code
  = f.input :ansi_name_code
  = f.input :languages
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :photo, as: :file
  = f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

And feature spec that looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Provider edit' do
  let(:admin)   { create(:user, :admin) }
  let(:provider) { create(:provider) }

  before do
    login_as admin
    visit edit_admin_provider_path(provider)
  end

  context 'when form is filled with invalid data' do
    before do
      fill_in 'First name', with: nil
      click_button 'Update provider'
    end

    scenario 'redirects to :edit' do
      expect(current_path).to eq admin_provider_path(provider)
    end

    scenario 'contains errors' do
      expect(page).to have_text "can't be blank"
    end
  end
end
```

This spec is failing. Capybara is not updating the First name input with nil value. But when I change input to this:

```
= f.input :photo
```

everything works as expected. Why is that?

Comment: filling in something with 'nil' is quite weird. Can you try with an empty string (e.g '') and see if it works?

Comment: I've tried that but thats not the solution...

Comment: What error are you getting for the failure?

Comment: I guess you should use `let!(:provider) { create(:provider) }`

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: I'm using Rack::Test